# Is the method read(byte b[], int off, int len) in InputStream same as the method read(byte b[], int off, int len) in FileInputStream?

Tags: java

I am a new Java programmer. When I read source code of Java 17, I want to know how the method of `read(byte b[], int off, int len)` works in FileInputStream, [FileInputStream's read method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV9oi.png). I found it returns readBytes which is a native method, [FileInputStream's native readBytes method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELq9x.png). I didn't learn C code, so I can't read OpenJDK's source code. When I read Java official documen, I noticed that sentences in `FileInputStream read(byte b[], int off, int len)`'s description: *"See Also:InputStream.read()"* ([Java official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQMVu.png)). I really found a method in InputStream with the same name and parameters.

So, I want to ask, are these two read methods the same? [InputStream's read method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76kI9.png)

Can I just read `InputStream's read(byte b[], int off, int len)` to replace the native read method in FileInputStream?

I didn't learn C code, so I can't read OpenJDK's source code. I try to resolve my question with Java official documentation.

Comment: Why not linke the official documentation that you found if it confuses you?

Comment: No, those methods are not the same, `FileInputStream` overrides the method with its own (faster) implementation

Comment: @Ferrybig So the only way to know how it works in code is to read openJDK code?

Comment: As a new Java programmer, why are you even trying to read this? You don't need read the Java implementation code to be able to *use* it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well,I want to lay a good foundation.If I just know how to use it instead of how it works,I may forget it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileInputStream` extends `InputStream` and overrides `read` in `InputStream`. Its difference can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html). They are not the same.

To be more specific, in `FileInputStream`, its [`readBytes`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c) calls `IO_read`(which finally calls `read` function in C) one time to read files.

`nread = IO_Read(fd, buf, len);`

While in `InputStream`, it calls `read()` byte by byte.

```
int c = read();
if (c == -1) {
    return -1;
}
b[off] = (byte)c;

int i = 1;
try {
    for (; i < len ; i++) {
        c = read();
        if (c == -1) {
            break;
        }
        b[off + i] = (byte)c;
    }
} catch (IOException ee) {
}
```

And because of its inheritance, you can call `InputStream`'s `read` using `super` keyword.